# Is using GetOldTweets3 against twitter policy? I believe not

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

GetOldTweets3 Is api with MIT licence, seems like a good api which work without much hassle with out any twitter developer account. Also I assume this api is not using twitter api it uses direct browser search the given query and **scrape** the tweet informations.

It’s not accurate and not having lot of features like twitter api but it does have its own way of working.

Most of the comment suggests it’s against twitter policy, my question is is it really is? Api **scrapes** tweets from publicly available website and tweets I couldn’t find any violation. Is it official that api violate terms with twitter.

Answer (score 1):

From their [TOS](https://twitter.com/en/tos)

> scraping the Services without the prior consent of Twitter is expressly prohibited

While they can't reliably stop scraping, they're free to recognize the automated interaction and block your bot.

Comment: Use of the Twitter API itself is perfectly OK if you have an approved developer account and a use case that is within Twitter's developer policy. You'll also get actual accurate data.